# Java generic definition in a static method

Tags: java, generics

I have the following problem when using java generic. Basically I need to do a conversion from an list of subtype to a list of its supertype, and I defines a method like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> getList(List<? extends T> input) {
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    list.addAll(input);
    return list;
}
```

However I'm not sure how I can invoke this method? Given type A, B extends A:

```
List<A> alist = getList(List<B> blist);
```

has a mismatch type, because in this case I only supply B's type information to the method invocation.

How can I invoke the method with the type information A supplied?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<B> blist = ...
List<A> alist = ClassName.<A>getList(blist);
```

Note that you could also just use `ArrayList`'s constructor here:

```
List<A> alist = new ArrayList<A>(blist);
```

Comment: I didn't know that you can do `ClassName.<A>getList(blist)` in java

Comment: @ColinD Shouldn't it be ClassName.<A, B>getList(blist)? Specifying both generic types? I seem to need that on my Java 6 compiler at least...

Comment: I think that the "just call the constructor" route is the way to go.

Comment: @Greg: No, the method only has one generic type parameter, `T`, and as such can only accept one type argument, `A` in this case. `A` matters because it's the return type we want. `B` doesn't matter so much other than that it must be a subtype of `A`.

Comment: @ColinD: ah, yes, you're correct. I was playing around with some code for this question and at one point I had a method that had two type parameters, but both don't need to be named, one can be a wildcard, my bad, thanks (I still think that just calling the constructor is likely the best approach ;)

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
public static void <T, S extends T> List<T> getList(List<S> input)
```

Comment: That doesn't add anything over the `List<? extends T>` version unfortunately. Calls still fail to compile without specifying type arguments.

Comment: that's right: there's no point to add S if it's only used once